# Odoo9 allways activate developer mode

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

Odoo 9 always activate developer mode for administrator.

Is it possible?

Comment: @Odedra I need always visible  https://postimg.cc/image/igrk1uivf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this [OCA app](https://github.com/OCA/server-tools/tree/9.0/base_technical_features) is what you need?

Comment: I'm install this module and check in user settings, but I don't see etc. on mouse hover field name....  When click on active developer mode in about all is visible (bug in right corner of page https://postimg.org/image/igrk1uivf/ ).

Comment: Oh sorry, i think i misunderstood your requirement. Just use a bookmark with debug parameter in the url?